# How to modifly kendoDatasource filter in requestStart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

I have the following requestStart in my kendoDatasource:

```
 requestStart: function (e) {
            var oldFilters = e.sender._filter ? e.sender._filter.filters : [],
                endDateTime;

            $.each(oldFilters, function (index, currFilter) {
                if (currFilter.field === 'StatusChangeDate' && currFilter.operator == 'eq') {
                    endDateTime = new Date(currFilter.value.getYear(), currFilter.value.getMonth(), currFilter.value.getDay(), 23, 59, 59);

                    oldFilters.push({ field: currFilter.field, operator: 'gt', value: currFilter.value });
                    oldFilters.push({ field: currFilter.field, operator: 'lt', value: endDateTime });
                    oldFilters.splice(index, 1);
                }
            });

            if (e.sender._filter) {
                e.sender._filter.filters = oldFilters;
            }
        },
```

I want to change DateTime filter when it's operator is 'eq', in order to disable filter precision.
But when I modify filter in requestStart like in the code above, it doesn't work. The request sends with old filter. 
I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Is there another way to achieve behavior like this?

Answer (score 0):

By the time requestStart is called, the query is already committed to being sent as is.  The event is just letting you know but doesn't give you the opportunity to change anything.

Rather than try to sneak in the back way, just call the dataSource's filter() method to filter any way you want.  DataSource will filter the data either locally or make a request to the server depending on the value of the serverFiltering option.

```
var filters = myDataSource.filter() || [],
    endDateTime;

$.each(filters, function (index, currFilter) {
    if (currFilter.field === 'StatusChangeDate' && currFilter.operator == 'eq') {
        endDateTime = new Date(currFilter.value.getYear(), currFilter.value.getMonth(), currFilter.value.getDay(), 23, 59, 59);

        filters.push({ field: currFilter.field, operator: 'gt', value: currFilter.value });
        filters.push({ field: currFilter.field, operator: 'lt', value: endDateTime });
        filters.splice(index, 1);
    }
});

// Now apply the new filter to the dataSource.  
// This will generate a request if serverFiltering == true.
myDataSource.filter(filters);
```

One other note, you should try to avoid accessing any property that starts with "_" as in "e.sender._filter".  This is generally considered to be a "private" property which could change with the next version.  You can get the current filter by calling filter() with no arguments as in the code above.  This is another general rule in Kendo, no args mean get a value, args mean set a value.

**EDIT**

You can also hijack the CRUD requests to modify and/or add parameters using the dataSource's [transport.parameterMap](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap) property.  Note that this method will not modify the dataSource's filter properties.  It only changes the request parameters going to the server.

```
$("#myGrid").kendoGrid({

    // Column definitions, etc...

    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {

            // create, read, update, destroy definitions...

            parameterMap: function(data, type) {
                if ((type === "read") && data.filter && data.filter.filters) {
                    var filters = data.filter.filters;
                    for (var index = 0; index < filters.length, index++) {
                        var currFilter = filters[index];
                        if (currFilter.field === 'StatusChangeDate' && currFilter.operator == 'eq') {
                            endDateTime = new Date(currFilter.value.getYear(), currFilter.value.getMonth(), currFilter.value.getDay(), 23, 59, 59);
                            filters.push({ field: currFilter.field, operator: 'gt', value: currFilter.value });
                            filters.push({ field: currFilter.field, operator: 'lt', value: endDateTime });
                            filters.splice(index, 1);
                            break;
                        }
                    });
                }

                return data;    
            }
        }
    }),
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. The actual problem is I can't figure out where to put this solution, I need to execute this additional filters when User applies filters in my StatusChangeDate column of kendoGrid. Is there any traditional way to get "Make filter" button of columnHeader?